# What's the difference between {foreach} and {section} in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

Can someone provide an example that make it clear?

Answer (score 1):

`{foreach}` is used to loop over an **associative array** as well a **numerically-indexed array,**

`{section}` which is for looping over **numerically-indexed arrays only**

The syntax for `{foreach}` is much easier than `{section}`, but as a tradeoff it can only be used for a single array

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.foreach.php) which explains the differences and provides examples.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.foreach.php):

> the syntax for {foreach} is much easier than {section}, **but as a tradeoff it can only be used for a single array**.

Comment: I've never heared of the term **single array**,what do you mean?

Comment: @yoyo `section` s can loop through nested arrays. `foreach` cannot.